# HTTPS support in WinCE6

Tags: embedded, windows-ce

I need to connect a WinCE6.0 device to a web based server using HTTPS.
The problem: WinCE6.0 uses WinInet v6 which supports SSL2, SSL3 and TSL1.0  None of which are supported in the current (2018) best practices due to their security flaws.

I doubt I can drop in a newer version of WinInet and expect it to run.
I had thoughts of porting CURL to WinCE.

I'm thinking this issue has already been addressed by the CE community, but I'm not seeing an available solution.

How can I get an old embedded device to securely connect to the WWW?

Answer (score 0):

From [GuruCE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75f9929d-e027-460c-9332-6ae09737fac2/https-on-wince6?forum=winembplatdev):

If you want to use TLS 1.1 and 1.2 on CE a suitable solution is to use [mbedTLS](https://tls.mbed.org/) library from ARM. It has a BSD-like license, so not too restrictive. Only one change to the makefiles is needed to get it to work on CE.